# Why fish is said to pose no risk despite the mercury on it?

Tags: food-poisoning

From Wikipedia :

> According to the US Food and Drug Administration (FDA), the risk from mercury by eating fish and shellfish is not a health concern for most people.

Also :

> Mercury is known to bioaccumulate in humans.

So why eating fish regularly is not a health concern? I'm talking even for lifetime time, imagine someone who's been eating a lot of fish for 30,50,70 years. All this mercury must cause some effect.

They want us to eat fish twice a week for Omega-3. That's 8 fish for month,96 a year. After 30 years following this advice you would have ate 2880 fish. How is this mercury not stacking up?

Comment: I would refer to to well written articles in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_in_fish and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)#Toxicity_and_safety. Do you have a concern or question which is not readily answered for example in these pages?

Comment: Yes, see my edited question now. I don't understand how one can eat a lot of fish for 40,50 years (Suppose i want to meet my Omega-3 needs from fish only) and still have no poisoning ?

Answer (score 1):

Mercury is stacking up. But the amount of mercury in fish differs not only by fish type, but also by fishing region. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_in_fish#Levels_of_contamination)

In most regions and with 'typical' amount of fish eaten, people do not eat enough fish to get dangerous mercury levels. -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_in_fish#Disparate_impacts